# Swipe carousal not working in Jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins

I am creating carousal using owl-carousel plugin basically I am carousal happen by swipe not by clicking(because it will run in tablet also).
I have created but my image are not showing up. Also please tell better plugin for carousal by swipe. It must Run desktop, mobile and tablets.

Also any comment about jquery code is also appreciated.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test page</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-device-width: 799px)" href="mobile-tablet.css" />-->


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>


    <!-- Important Owl stylesheet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css">

<!-- Default Theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/owl-carousel/owl.theme.css">

<!-- Include js plugin -->
<script src="plugins/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>



    <style>
    #owl-demo .item img{
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body id="mainbody">
    <div data-role="page" id="mainpage">


              <div id="content1" class="ui-grid-b ui-responsive">
            <section id="slider">

      <!--     <img class="carousalimg" src="images/banner1.png" alt="" />-->




<div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel">

  <div class="item"><img src="images/banner1.png" alt="The Last of us"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="images/banner1.png" alt="GTA V"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="images/banner1.png" alt="Mirror Edge"></div>

</div>


            </section>
        </div><!-- /content -->



    </div><!-- /page -->
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

  $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({

      navigation : true, // Show next and prev buttons
      slideSpeed : 300,
      paginationSpeed : 400,
      singleItem:true

      // "singleItem:true" is a shortcut for:
      // items : 1, 
      // itemsDesktop : false,
      // itemsDesktopSmall : false,
      // itemsTablet: false,
      // itemsMobile : false

  });

});
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

ui-page.ui-body-c {
    background:url(../images/bluebg.jpg) !important;;
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
    background-position:center center;
    background-size:cover;  
}

#mainpage{
    position:relative;
}
#content1{
    position:absolute;
    left: 17%;
    top: 20%;
}
#slider{
    width: 100%;

    /*background-color: #fbfbfb;
    border: 1px solid #b8b8b8;*/
}
/*#slider .carousalimg{
    max-width:100%;

}*/
```

Comment: instead of `$(document).ready(function() {` use `$(document).on("pageshow", "#mainpage", function () {`.

Comment: My carousal is working but image is not showing in the page.

Comment: if you just add the image tag outside the carousel, do you see the image? Are you sure the path is correct?